# storing images in an S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a JavaScript front end which makes a network request to my backend.  My backend is trying to store an image to an S3 bucket and I am getting the following error:

```
No such file or directory: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/c3f34872-ab27-49d3-93b8-eb4f01216110'
```

I think the issue is coming from the way I am formatting the image to send in a network request:

```
  function onImageChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let img = event.target.files[0];
      setFormData({
        name: "background_image",
        value: URL.createObjectURL(img),
      });
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to send images from the front end, but any help would be appreciated.

```
<input
  type="file"
  name="myImage"
  accept="image/*"
  onChange={onImageChange}
/>
```

Comment: what event is `onImageChange` a handler for?

Comment: An input field which accepts images. I will update my question.

Comment: Is the error in the back end or the front end?

Comment: I see the error in the back end, but I think the issue is the front end image is not being formatted in a way my server understands.

Comment: That would depend on what your back end is expecting. How does it handle the image?